# Making a prediction function using Tensorflow for Time Series Analysis

Tags: python, sql, tensorflow

I'm currently working on a python script for my Thesis project. After building an sqlite3 database which stores values related to active energy (AE) consumption at my college campus every 15 minutes, my task is to build a neural network model to predict future values by analyzing the previous values already collected. In other words, I must do time series forecasting.

Being a complete novice in the world of machine learning, I closely followed the tutorial posted on tensorflow's official website, (link:(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series)), using many of the classes and functions defined there (most importantly the WindowGenerator class).

Roughly, my goal is to predict values of active energy consumption for the next X time steps after looking at Y previous time steps.

After building all the kinds of models shown on the tutorial website, and comparing them, I want to build a function that queries the past x time steps of data from the database, prepares an input dataset to be fed into the model for prediction, and then graphs the predictions along with the real values. I'm having a lot of trouble here, and it seems most of it comes from my lack of understanding of the "shape" of these models.

Here is the part of the code which queries and processes data for model training. (No problems here, the process was very similar to the tutorial's explanation):

```
import os
import datetime
import IPython
import IPython.display
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,14)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False
            
def plot_2_values_full(df,plot_cols,title_top,title_bottom): #dataframe and list of plot columns, saves table of statistical sata as PNG

    plot_features=df[plot_cols]
    axes = plot_features.plot(subplots=True)
    axes[0].set_title(title_top)
    axes[1].set_title(title_bottom)
    plt.show()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    table_data = df.describe().transpose().round(5)
    table=ax.table(cellText=table_data.values,
            colLabels=table_data.columns,
            rowLabels=table_data.index,
            cellLoc = 'center', 
            loc='center')
    table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    table.set_fontsize(7)  # Adjust as necessary
    table.scale(1, 1.5) 
    ax.axis('off')

    # Shading
    cells = table.properties()["children"]
    for cell in cells:
        cell.set_edgecolor("black")  # set cell border color
        if cell.get_text().get_text() in table_data.columns:  # column names
            cell.set_facecolor("#ffafaf")  # change color as needed
        else:  # value cells
            cell.set_facecolor("#dafaff")  # change color as needed

    plt.savefig('data_summary_full.png', bbox_inches='tight')

def plot_2_values_between_dates(df,plot_cols,start_date,end_date,title_top,title_bottom): #dataframe and list of plot columns

    plot_features = df.loc[start_date:end_date, plot_cols]
    axes = plot_features.plot(subplots=True)
    axes[0].set_title(title_top)
    axes[1].set_title(title_bottom)
    plt.show()

def check_important_frequencies(df,column):
    fft = tf.signal.rfft(df[column])
    f_per_dataset = np.arange(0, len(fft))

    n_samples_h = len(df[column])
    hours_per_year = 24*365.2524
    years_per_dataset = n_samples_h/(hours_per_year)

    f_per_year = f_per_dataset/years_per_dataset
    plt.figure()
    plt.step(f_per_year, np.abs(fft))
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.ylim(0, 400000)
    plt.xlim([0.1, max(plt.xlim())])
    plt.xticks([1, 365.2524], labels=['1/Year', '1/day'])
    _ = plt.xlabel('Frequency (log scale)')
    plt.show()

def normalize_split_df(df):

    n = len(df)
    train_df = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
    val_df = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
    test_df = df[int(n*0.9):]

    train_mean = train_df.mean()
    train_std = train_df.std()

    train_df = (train_df - train_mean) / train_std
    val_df = (val_df - train_mean) / train_std
    test_df = (test_df - train_mean) / train_std

    df_std = (df - train_mean) / train_std


    #Violin Plot
    df_std = df_std.melt(var_name='Column', value_name='Normalized')
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    ax = sns.violinplot(x='Column', y='Normalized', data=df_std)
    _ = ax.set_xticklabels(df.keys(), rotation=90)
    plt.show()

    return train_df,val_df,test_df,df_std,train_mean,train_std

def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=2):
  early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=patience,
                                                    mode='min')

  model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

  history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=window.val,
                      callbacks=[early_stopping])
  return history

def datetime_feature_engineering(df,date_time_col):
    timestamp_s = date_time_col.map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)
    day = 24*60*60
    year = (365.2425)*day

    df['Day sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
    df['Day cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
    df['Year sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))
    df['Year cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))

    #remove fecha column which is now useless
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) #df['fecha]=pd.to_datetime(df['fecha]) SETS FECHA AS INDEX. Need to reset that before dropping.
    df.drop('fecha', axis=1, inplace=True)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(np.array(df['Day sin'])[:250])
    plt.plot(np.array(df['Day cos'])[:250])
    plt.xlabel('Time [h]')
    plt.title('Time of day signal')
    plt.show()

    return df

############################################################################################
print("STEP 1: QUERYING DATA")

#SQL query to select data
query = "SELECT fecha, valor, is_schoolday, temp  FROM AE WHERE fecha between '2022-10-22' AND '2023-04-30'"

#Create SQLDataset object to read data from database
dataset = tf.data.experimental.SqlDataset("sqlite", r"trainbase.sqlite3"
                                          ,query,(tf.string,tf.string,tf.string,tf.string))

############################################################################################
print("STEP 2:FEATURE EXTRACTION, PLOTTING AND DATAFRAME CREATION")

data = []
for element in dataset:
    fecha, valor, is_schoolday, temp = element
    fecha = fecha.numpy().decode()
    valor = float(valor.numpy().decode())
    is_schoolday = float(is_schoolday.numpy().decode())
    temp = float(temp.numpy().decode())
    data.append([fecha, valor, is_schoolday, temp])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['fecha', 'valor', 'is_schoolday', 'temp'])
df['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'])
#df.set_index('fecha', inplace=True)

print(df.head())

cols=['valor','temp']
top="AE"
bottom="TEMP"

#plot_2_values_full(df,cols,top,bottom)
#plot_2_values_between_dates(df,cols,'2023-03-30','2023-04-30',top,bottom)
#check_important_frequencies(df,'valor')
#check_important_frequencies(df,'temp')

############################################################################################
print("STEP 3: DATETIME FEATURE ENGINEERING")

date_times=df['fecha']
df=datetime_feature_engineering(df,date_times)

############################################################################################
print("STEP 4: SPLIT AND NORMALIZE DATA")

column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}
num_features = df.shape[1]
train_df,val_df,test_df,df_std,train_mean,train_std=normalize_split_df(df)

print("num features:",num_features)
print("train mean=:",train_mean)
print("train std=:",train_std)

############################################################################################
print("STEP 5: DATA WINDOWING AND MODEL TRAINING")

class WindowGenerator():
    def __init__(self,input_width,label_width,shift,train_df=train_df,val_df=val_df,test_df=test_df,label_columns=None):
        
        #Store the raw data:
        self.train_df=train_df
        self.val_df = val_df
        self.test_df = test_df

        # Work out the label column indices.
        self.label_columns = label_columns
        if label_columns is not None:
            self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
        self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)}

        # Work out the window parameters.
        self.input_width = input_width
        self.label_width = label_width
        self.shift = shift

        self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

        self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
        self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

        self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
        self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
        self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join([
            f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
            f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
            f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
            f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])
    
    def split_window(self, features):
        inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
        labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
        if self.label_columns is not None:
            labels = tf.stack(
                [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
                axis=-1)

        # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
        # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
        inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
        labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

        return inputs,labels

    def plot(self, model=None, plot_col='valor', max_subplots=3):
        inputs, labels = self.example
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
        max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
        for n in range(max_n):
            plt.subplot(max_n, 1, n+1)
            plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} [normed]')
            plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
                    label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

            if self.label_columns:
                label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
            else:
                label_col_index = plot_col_index

            if label_col_index is None:
                continue

            plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                        edgecolors='k', label='Labels', c='#2ca02c', s=64)
            if model is not None:
                predictions = model(inputs)
                plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                        marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                        c='#ff7f0e', s=64)

            if n == 0:
                plt.legend()

            plt.xlabel('Time [15 minute steps]')
            plt.show()
        
    def make_dataset(self, data):
        data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
        ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
            data=data,
            targets=None,
            sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
            sequence_stride=1,
            shuffle=True,
            batch_size=32,)

        ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

        return ds
    
    @property
    def train(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)

    @property
    def test(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)


    #Standard example batch for easy access and plotting
    @property
    def example(self):
        """Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
        result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
        if result is None:
            # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
            result = next(iter(self.train))
            # And cache it for next time
            self._example = result
        return result

MAX_EPOCHS = 20

OUT_STEPS = 96

multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=96*7,
                               label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                               shift=OUT_STEPS)
multi_val_performance={}
multi_performance={}

#DENSE
multi_dense_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Take the last time step.
    # Shape [batch, time, features] => [batch, 1, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :]),
    # Shape => [batch, 1, dense_units]
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    # Shape => [batch, out_steps*features]
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features,
                          kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()),
    # Shape => [batch, out_steps, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])
])

history = compile_and_fit(multi_dense_model, multi_window)
IPython.display.clear_output()
multi_window.plot(multi_dense_model)
multi_dense_model.save("multidense.h5")

############################################################################################
```

(note some of the keys are in Spanish: 'valor' = value (of the active energy, i.e. the target value) and 'fecha' = datetime)

Since the time steps are 15 minutes each, 96 output steps means we are predicting 24h of data in the future, and 96*7 input_width means the model is using 7 days of previous data for this prediction.

So, having trained and saved the model, I want to import it to a different file. Here, I want to query some new, unseen data (in this case, the data recorded on the week of May 1st 2023-May 7th 2023) and use it to predict the values of the next 24h (May 9th). Here is where I'm having trouble. What I have so far is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

model=tf.keras.models.load_model("multidense.h5")

#train mean: 
#valor           46.677566
#is_schoolday     0.511261
#temp             9.330935
#Day sin         -0.000142
#Day cos         -0.000851
#Year sin        -0.060694
#Year cos         0.793617
#dtype: float64

#train std: 
# valor           28.941530
#is_schoolday     0.499893
#temp             5.347442
#Day sin          0.707416
#Day cos          0.706853
#Year sin         0.577324
#Year cos         0.182251
#dtype: float64

def query_trainbase_data_4prediction(input_width):
    query = f"SELECT fecha, valor, is_schoolday, temp FROM AE ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT {input_width}"
    database=r"trainbase.sqlite3"
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.SqlDataset("sqlite", database, query, (tf.string, tf.string, tf.string, tf.string))

    data = []

    for element in dataset:
        fecha, valor, is_schoolday, temp = element
        fecha = fecha.numpy().decode()
        valor = float(valor.numpy().decode())
        is_schoolday = float(is_schoolday.numpy().decode())
        temp = float(temp.numpy().decode())
        data.append([fecha, valor, is_schoolday, temp])

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['fecha', 'valor', 'is_schoolday', 'temp'])
    print(df.head())

    return df

def prepare_queried_data(df,input_width=672):

    df['valor'] = (df['valor'] - 46.677566) / 28.941530
    df['temp']=(df['temp'] - 9.330935) / 5.347442

    date_time=pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'])
    timestamp_s = date_time.map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)

    day = 24*60*60
    year = (365.2425)*day

    df['Day sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
    df['Day cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
    df['Year sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))
    df['Year cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))

    df['Day sin']=(df['Day sin'] +0.000142) / 0.707416
    df['Day cos']=(df['Day cos'] + 0.000851) / 0.706853
    df['Year sin']=(df['Day sin'] + 0.60694) / 0.577324
    df['Year cos']=(df['Year cos'] - 0.793617) / 0.182251

    df.drop('fecha',axis=1,inplace=True)
        
    # Convert your DataFrame to a TensorFlow Dataset
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df.to_dict(orient='list'))

    return ds
    
data=query_trainbase_data_4prediction(672)
dataset=prepare_queried_data(data)

pred=model.predict(dataset)
print(pred.shape)
```

This is throwing an error:

" ValueError: Missing data for input "lambda_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['valor', 'is_schoolday', 'temp', 'Day sin', 'Day cos', 'Year sin', 'Year cos']. Expected the following keys: ['lambda_input']
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp_*autograph_generated_filew8wkqbqi.py", line 15, in tf__predict_function
retval* = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: Missing data for input "lambda_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['valor', 'is_schoolday', 'temp', 'Day sin', 'Day cos', 'Year sin', 'Year cos']. Expected the following keys: ['lambda_input']"

I know this has to do with the lambda layer defined in the sequential model, but I really have no idea how to tackle this error or even if this script makes sense for predictions. My final goal is to graph the real data against the model's predictions for the day of May 9th. To do this, I've queried the data from May 1st to May 8th (1 week, or 672 data points) because I've trained the model to predict 24h based on the last week of data. So, if I understand this correctly, the model should take this input and spit out 96 data points, which are the normalized prediction values for May 9th.

Am I on the right track here? What could this "lambda_input" error mean exactly? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time if you read all of this.

Really don't know how to fix the "lambda_input" error. I can only assume there is something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm trying to predict the data.

Comment: Is this perhaps caused by serializing and de-serializing the model? The [Lambda docs mention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) a warning about serialization which you should look at.

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :]),` Isn't this taking the last time step, and ignoring everything before that? This seems crazy. What if there's an upward or downward trend in the data? Your model will be unable to see that.

Comment: @NickODell I believe you're right. This is how it was defined in the tutorial. Bear in mind, while I've grasped the over arching scope of the code, I really do not yet have an understanding of the mathematical theory behind classical time series analysis. I can't explain why the author of the tutorial decided to define the model this way. 

Perhaps I could include use n time steps ( x[:, -n:, :] instead of s[:, -1:, :]).

Right now, I'm more interested in whether or not I'm interpreting this model correctly and what thie "lambda_input" key error is talking about.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).